# Creating a text file with user entered name using c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

hi i have a webform where i am trying to create a txt file in a particular directory but i want to the name of the txt file to be entered by the user but I am not getting it how to do it please help

the code below creates a text file with name NameBox.Text.ToString I dont want that please help and thanks.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameLabel.Visible = false;
        NameBox.Visible = false;
       submit.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameLabel.Visible = true;
        NameBox.Visible = true;
        submit.Visible = true;

    }

    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // string fname = NameBox.Text;

        string path = @"D:\NameBox.Text.ToString.txt";
    try
    {

        // Delete the file if it exists. 
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Note that no lock is put on the 
            // file and the possibility exists 
            // that another process could do 
            // something with it between 
            // the calls to Exists and Delete.
            File.Delete(path);
        }

        // Create the file. 
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
            // Add some information to the file.
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }

        // Open the stream and read it back. 
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string s = "";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: webform, Console, accessing D:, wow... u need to take a step back and reconsider what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

First, keep in mind that your IIS will not allow you to access your local file System as you expcect in a "console" application, maybe running with local admin rights.

Second, be sware of illegal characters for file names, you need to check or replace it.

And third, what if two users decide to use the same filename?

As Dejan Dakic already mentioned, step back and reconsider, maybe about using a database, like SQLite or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = @"D:\NameBox.Text.ToString.txt";
```

That won't work. if your textfield is called "NameBox" you need to access the value of its text which is not possible within a String.

Try this:

```
String path = @"D:\" + NameBox.Text + ".txt";
```

If you're new to programming, I'd suggest to go get a book or some tutorials and get started that way! :)

Comment: Thank You for your suggestions I will consider them all specially the book and tutorials one.